# Recursion Limit Reached and Segmentation Fault

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, recursion, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I know that these kinds of questions have been asked quite a lot and none of them helped me.

In the problem below, I'm trying to implement Strong Connected Components of a directed graph with a **huge size**. 
Here is my code.

```
import os 
import sys
os.system('cls')
sys.setrecursionlimit(22764)

from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

## Reading the data in adjacency list form
data = open("data.txt", 'r')
G = defaultdict( list )

for line in data:
    lst = [int(s) for s in line.split()]
    G[lst[0]].append( lst[1] ) 


print 'Graph has been read!'



def rev_graph(  ):
    revG = defaultdict( list )
    data = open( "data.txt", 'r' )    


    for line in data:
        lst = [ int(s) for s in line.split() ]
        revG[ lst[1] ].append( lst[0] ) 

    print 'Graph has been reversed!'
    return revG


class Track(object):
    """Keeps track of the current time, current source, component leader,
    finish time of each node and the explored nodes."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_time = 0
        self.current_source = None
        self.leader = {}
        self.finish_time = {}
        self.explored = set()


def dfs(graph_dict, node, track):
    """Inner loop explores all nodes in a SCC. Graph represented as a dict,
    {tail node: [head nodes]}. Depth first search runs recrusively and keeps
    track of the parameters"""

    # print 'In Recursion node is ' + str(node)
    track.explored.add(node)
    track.leader[node] = track.current_source
    for head in graph_dict[node]:


        if head not in track.explored:
                dfs(graph_dict, head, track)

    track.current_time += 1

    track.finish_time[node] = track.current_time


def dfs_loop(graph_dict, nodes, track):
    """Outter loop checks out all SCCs. Current source node changes when one
    SCC inner loop finishes."""

    for node in nodes:

        if node not in track.explored:


            track.current_source = node
            dfs(graph_dict, node, track)


def scc(graph, nodes):
    """First runs dfs_loop on reversed graph with nodes in decreasing order,
    then runs dfs_loop on orignial graph with nodes in decreasing finish
    time order(obatined from firt run). Return a dict of {leader: SCC}."""

    out = defaultdict(list)
    track = Track()

    reverse_graph = rev_graph(  )


    global G
    G = None

    dfs_loop(reverse_graph, nodes, track) ## changes here

    sorted_nodes = sorted(track.finish_time,
                          key=track.finish_time.get, reverse=True)

    # print sorted_nodes
    track.current_time = 0
    track.current_source = None
    track.explored = set()

    reverse_graph = None


    dfs_loop(graph, sorted_nodes, track)
    for lead, vertex in groupby(sorted(track.leader, key=track.leader.get),
                                key=track.leader.get):
        out[lead] = list(vertex)
    return out


maxNode = max( G.keys() )   
revNodes = list( reversed( range( 1, ( maxNode + 1 ) ) ) )

ans = scc( G, revNodes )
print 'naman'
print ans
```

Now, at this recursion limit, I get Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) error. Below this limit, I get 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp' error.

I'm also attaching the data file. Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8J7t96hLKJwQzREbVRwbHBoLVE/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: You have 2 possibilities: Increase the recursion depth (I think that's possible in Python) or change some parts of your algorithm into iterative.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to increase the recursion depth.

Answer (score 1):

Rakete1111 gave you the basic principle: don't use recursion for this.  You can easily maintain global lists of nodes explored and waiting; as it is, you've done a lot of overhead to pass these around your methods.

If you want a small attempt at getting this to work quickly, start by making **track** a global.  Right now, you're passing a unique instance your traversal routines -- on every call, you'll have to instantiate a local copy, which burns a fair amount of storage.

Also, each call incurs a relatively heavy memory penalty, as you pass your status lists down to the next call level.  If you replace your recursions with loops saying "while list not empty", you'll be able to save a lot of memory and all those recursive calls.  Can you unwind that yourself?  Post a comment if you need coding help.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to increase the recursion depth. You are right when you say that I can maintain track as a global variable and save a lot of memory. But, the recursion limit is gonna reach anyway. So do you have any other way to do it without recursion like some different implementation.

Comment: Yes -- however, teaching you how to convert recursion to iteration is, in general, beyond he scope of Stack Overflow.  Search out the other questions on that topic.  For a good start, are you familiar with Dijkstra's algorithm for finding graph paths?  You can harness those basics for your conversion; SCC isn't much more complicated in control flow.